# What can I do to make sure my header doesn't overlap the status bar?

Tags: jquery, ios, css

I am having trouble with my iOS status bar and the header overlapping. Using CSS, I can successfully move the header down, but then as a scroll on the page, the page content goes under the header and appears over top of the status bar. This is the code that I use.

```
[name=mobileheader] { 
height: 98px; 
margin-top: 20px;
}
```

I have also tried this scenario but the buttons in the header don't move down with it so they still overlap the status bar.

```
[name=mobileheader] { 
height: 98px; 
padding-top: 20px;
}
```

How can I get the buttons to move down with the rest of the header? Or if anyone has other suggestions as to how to get the header to not overlap the status bar I would take them!

Answer (score 1):

Add z-index to your mobileheader. See if that works.

```
[name=mobileheader] { 
height: 98px; 
padding-top: 20px;
z-index:10;
}
```

try adding class="clearfix" to your mobile-header. if you are using bootstrap. If you are not then add this to your css

Add this to you css

```
.clearfix:after {
     visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     font-size: 0;
     content: " ";
     clear: both;
     height: 0;
     }
```

Comment: Adding z-index didn't change anything.

Comment: try adding class="clearfix" to your mobile-header. if you are using bootstrap. If you are not then add this to your css

Comment: It didn't work. I am not using bootstrap but I am using JQuery so I was able to add the "clearfix" class to the header as well as the button then add the code to a css file but it only removed the symbol in the button instead of moving the button.

Comment: dont apply it to the button

Comment: apply only to the header. what this clearfix class does it it extends the parent elements height so that it covers its child elements

Comment: so that content below this parent does not overlap with its child

Comment: I think I have found the problem, but I'm not sure how to solve it. I am using JQuery and PhoneGap. It works with a button that is text only, but all of my buttons are icon-only so it doesn't work.